# Proof of $\sum_{i=0}^{N_s - 1} e^{-j2\pi n(k'-k)/N_s} = N_s\delta(k'-k)$

Tags: proof-verification, physics, integers, dirac-delta

Currently, I'm faced with this problem:

> Prove that this property holds when $N_s$ is an even integer, for any integers $n$, $k'$, $k$: 
>   $\sum_{i=0}^{N_s - 1} e^{-j2\pi n(k'-k)/N_s} = N_s\delta(k'-k)$

I initially saw this problem as one that could be solved by proof by induction. For example, the base case:

Let $N_s = 2$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2 - 1} e^{-j2\pi n(k'-k)/N_s} = 2\delta(k'-k)$$
$$e^{-j2\pi (0)(k'-k)/N_s} + e^{-j2\pi (1)(k'-k)/N_s}= 2\delta(k'-k)$$
$$1 + e^{-j2\pi (0)(k'-k)/N_s} = 2\delta(k'-k)$$
Case 1: Let $k'-k = 0$:
$$1+e^{0} = 2\delta(0)$$
$$2 = 2$$
Case 2: Let $\delta(k'- k) = 1$
$$1+e^{-j\pi} = 2\delta(1)$$
$$1 + cos(-\pi) + jsin(-\pi)) = 2\delta(1)$$
$$1 + (-1 + 0) = 2\delta(1)$$
$$0 = 0$$

However, when it comes to the induction step, I haven't gotten the proof to actually work out. In particular, what I did was Let $N_s = 2m$ for some $m$ in the Integers, and try and prove $N_s = 2(m+1)$. But based on the base case you might be able to spot a pattern that proved problematic in my own proof. For example in the first case, there will always be $1 + (2m-1)(1) = (2m+2)\delta(0)$. Which is certainly not equivalent, and makes me think that induction isn't the best course of action for a proof in this case, and I am way overthinking it. I'm thinking that some usage of Euler's formula in a direct proof might be a better route, but I believe I should be close on the logic with two different cases for k' and k.

Would someone be able to help me out with this proof? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Looks like a geometric progression to me.

Comment: $1+e^{0} = 2\delta(0)$ is not true; it's not even defined.